# Is the story of Arakawa Under the Bridge that cuts off in anime continued in manga?

Tags: arakawa-under-the-bridge

I've watched 2 seasons of Arakawa and it seems that the story didn't get adapted into anime in full. Namely, we know that Nino must leave for Venus soon, but she doesn't even in the final episode. And we haven't seen her parents yet, which she claims called her there. Does it all happen in manga or do both versions suddenly stop at the same point?